# electron sending data from ipcMain to ipcRender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

In my React Component to load data from file in `componentDidMount` i make empty send `ipcRenderer.send("loading", "go");` to activate `ipcMain` listener and make him send data to `ipcRenderer` listener in React Component. Can i make electron send data when app starts to `ipcRenderer` listener without empty sending.

React Component Code:

```
componentDidMount(){
ipcRenderer.send("loading", "go");

ipcRenderer.on("sending", (event, arg) => {
  let arg_sorted = arg.tasks.sort((a,b) => this.dateSord(a.date, b.date));
  this.setState({
    items: arg_sorted,
  });
});}
```

Electron:

```
ipcMain.on("loading", (event, arg) => {
   let data = store.parseFile();
   event.sender.send("sending", data); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I make electron send data when app starts

Not immediately, because your `BrowserWindow` isn't ready yet. But you can use [`'dom-ready'`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-dom-ready) event to be in the right time.

```
win.webContents.on('dom-ready', () => {
  let data = ...
  win.webContents.send('sending', data)
})
win.loadURL(...)
```